# Repeater's reload after inserting new item

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, repeater

I am creating very simple discussion forum in asp.net c#. It is repeater which loads and inserts data from xml file. Loading of comments from xml file works normally fine, but after inserting new comment to the xml file it does not. After click on insert button it inserts new comment into xml file, but then the repeater cannot load any data from the same xml file. I tryed to rebind repeater in click event, but it does not works.

Here is my code for inserting data into XML(using xmldocument class).

```
XmlNode author = doc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//author[@id={0}]",Request.QueryString["id"]));
XmlNode comment = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "comment", "");
XmlNode name = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "name", "");
name.InnerText = nameTxb.Text.Trim();
XmlNode date = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "date", "");
date.InnerText = string.Format("{0:D}", DateTime.Now);
XmlNode message = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "message", "");
message.InnerText = messageTxb.Text.Trim();
comment.AppendChild(name);
comment.AppendChild(date);
comment.AppendChild(message);
author.AppendChild(comment);
doc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/discussion.xml"));
nameTxb.Text = "";
messageTxb.Text = "";
Repeater1.DataSourceID = "XmlDataSource1";
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

The XML fragment looks like this:

```
<comment>
  <name>...</name>
  <date>...</date>
  <message>...</message>
</comment>
```

Comment: What is XmlDataSource1? Is that being updated at the same time as you saving your xml file?

Comment: Also, are you binding to your data source originally in `Page_Load()`? If so, did you make sure to only do that after ensuring that you aren't in a postback?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `XmlDataSource1.DataFile` after saving the xml and may also need to set the XPath like below:

```
doc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/discussion.xml"));
nameTxb.Text = "";
messageTxb.Text = "";
XmlDataSource1.DataFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/discussion.xml");
XmlDataSource1.XPath = "root/author[@id='" + Request.QueryString["id"] + "']/comment";//root is the root in discussion.xml
```

**Here's how I have tested your code:**

I had the following xml file `discussion.xml` in `App_Data`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <author id="1">
    <comment>
      <name>John Doe</name>
      <date>Wednesday, December 4, 2013</date>
      <message>Test Message</message>
    </comment>
  </author>
</root>
```

**Here's my markup:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <h3><%# XPath ("name") %></h3>
              <b>Date:</b>
              <%# XPath ("date") %>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server"
             DataFile="~/App_Data/discussion.xml"
             XPath="root/author[@id='1']/comment">
        </asp:XmlDataSource>
        <asp:TextBox ID="nameTxb" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="messageTxb" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**And in codebehind I have this method:**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string auid = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]) ? "1" : Request.QueryString["id"];

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/discussion.xml"));
    XmlNode author = doc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//author[@id={0}]", auid));
    XmlNode comment = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "comment", "");
    comment.InnerText = messageTxb.Text;
    XmlNode name = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "name", "");
    name.InnerText = nameTxb.Text.Trim();
    XmlNode date = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "date", "");
    date.InnerText = string.Format("{0:D}", DateTime.Now);
    XmlNode message = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "message", "");
    message.InnerText = messageTxb.Text.Trim();
    comment.AppendChild(name);
    comment.AppendChild(date);
    comment.AppendChild(message);
    author.AppendChild(comment);
    doc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/discussion.xml"));
    nameTxb.Text = "";
    messageTxb.Text = "";
    XmlDataSource1.DataFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/discussion.xml");
    XmlDataSource1.XPath = "root/author[@id='" + auid + "']/comment";
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}
```